# why crash my app when use the Material button?

Tags: java, android, material-design, build.gradle

I want to use the materail button but when I write and run the program the program crashes.
What do I need help with?

**This my code**

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"/>
```

**This build.gradle**

```html
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.pwittchen:swipe-rx2:0.3.0'
    implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:2.0.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:2.0.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MaterialButton to work, App theme must inherit from Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant)

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">`

Comment: I'm happy to help!